# Using colon for aliase breaks autocomplete

Tags: bash, alias, autocomplete

I'm using colon or other prefix for aliases in `.bashrc`.

For a while I was using short keys like:

```
alias :t="tmux"
alias :www="google-chrome --use-gl=desktop &>/dev/null &"
alias :ide="bash ~/netbeans-11.3/netbeans/bin/netbeans &>/dev/null &"
alias :bsh="/bin/bash"
alias :c="clear"
alias :d="docker"
alias :dc="docker-compose"
```

And it worked. But I faced the issue that autocomplete doesn't work because of colon:

`complete -F _docker :d`

When I invoke the completion of `:d`, nothing is displayed at all.

Is it a collision? How can I fix it? Do you see more collisions coming? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you set alias for both "d" and ":d" and issue the `complete -F _docker :d`

Answer (score 3):

Colons are not illegal in Bash [alias](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#Aliases) names. The explicitly disallowed characters are `\`, `"`, `'`, `<space>`, `<tab>`, `<newline>`, `|`, `&`, `;`, `(`, `)`, `<`, `>`,  `/`, `$`, `` ` ``, `=`.

Assuming you have [bash-completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion) installed, you will likely face two issues (the first one being about aliases in general, regardless of any colon in their names):

1. Completion functions are loaded lazily:

   ```bsh
     # In a freshly opened shell
   $ alias bar='docker'
   $ complete -F _docker bar
   $ declare -pF _docker
   bash: declare: _docker: not found
     # Typing "bar", TAB, TAB:
   $ bar bash: completion: function `_docker' not found
   ```

   To work around this you may explicitly load the functions you need (or write a wrapper around the default completion function, `_completion_loader`, and make it handle aliases too):

   ```
     # ...continue
   $ _completion_loader docker
   $ declare -pF _docker
   declare -f _docker
     # Typing "bar", TAB, TAB:
   $ bar 
   attach     container  ...
   ```
2. [Readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Line-Editing.html#Command-Line-Editing) (the library providing line editing and [programmable completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html#Programmable-Completion) in Bash) treats the characters included in the [`COMP_WORDBREAKS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-COMP_005fWORDBREAKS) variable as word separators, and by default `:` is among them—to support use cases such as the assignment to variables (e.g. `PATH`) that contain colon-separated lists of paths.
   Thus, attempting to complete the `:foo`  command line gives the completion function a spoiled array of words to complete. Specifically, the elements in [`COMP_WORDS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-COMP_005fWORDS) will be `:`, `foo` and one empty string instead of `:foo` and one empty string.

   This is mentioned in bash-completion's [FAQ on GitHub](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion#faq). See "Q. Completion goes awry when I try to complete on something that contains a colon."

   The only solution proposed in that FAQ is to backslash-escape colons on the command line:

   ```
     # In a freshly opened shell
   $ alias :foo='docker'
   $ complete -F _docker :foo
   $ _completion_loader docker
     # Typing "\:foo", TAB, TAB:
   $ \:foo 
   attach     container  ...
   ```

   Unfortunately, though, prepending a backslash to a command prevents Bash from performing alias expansion, leading to a "command not found" error. This solution would however work if defining a function (e.g. `:d () { docker "$@"; }`) instead of an alias was an option for you.

   Of course, you may alternatively remove `:` from `COMP_WORDBREAKS`, but this would break automatic completion of `PATH`-like command lines:

   ```
   $ COMP_WORDBREAKS=${COMP_WORDBREAKS/:/}
     #  Typing "PATH=/bin:/", TAB doesn't complete any further:
   $ PATH=/bin:/
   ```

Comment: And it might be worth mentioning that the colon is probably a word separator for autocompletion since it's used as a separator in `PATH`. So it makes something like `PATH=$PATH:/path/somew<tab>` work. (...well, the linked FAQ mentions that as the reason too, so strike the "probably")

Comment: Thank you for your afford. I just have to point out that 1) I don't have issue with completion functions by itself - it works okay with alias `d`. 2) Backslash doesn't seem to work as you described.

Comment: @ilkkachu That is implied in the sentence/example I eventually added at the end of my answer. I agree it'd seem more appropriate to mention it together with `COMP_WORDBREAKS`, though.

Comment: @Yevgen About (1): I didn't mean to imply that; and I edited my answer to clarify that I'm also addressing general issues that others may face. About (2): that is what the linked FAQ suggests and what happens on the systems I could use for testing. Isn't it working for you? Does it still print nothing instead of the suggested completions? (Note that `"\:foo"` in my code snippet is a comment, the actually typed string is `\:foo`).

Comment: Backslash does not work due to: `:d: command not found`. I have tried define alias with backslash to fix this but that didn't go. Anyway, i think I had enough of it for now - I've got the basic understanding what is happening so I'm fine with `_d` unless someone will suggest a better idea.

Comment: @Yevgen Right, the backslash is a form of quoting and prevents alias expansion. I've tried addressing that too.